# Salesforce Flow: Create record from sObject variable of another object type

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm trying to build a flow (using Visual Workflow) to achieve the following:

1. Cycle through Contracts object and find Contracts based on specific filters
2. Create Leads from the information captured from those Contracts
3. Update the a lookup field in the Contracts with the associated Lead Id

Flow currently looks like this:

[image: Current Flow]

My current issue is that the flow is trying to create 'Contracts' rather than 'Leads' since the sObject variable used to store the Contract information is linked to Contracts. Is there a way to loop the sObject variable into a Lead related sObject variable so I can use this for the 'Fast Create' element? Any advice to assist with this Flow would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SF provided answer:

https://salesforcesidekick.com/2015/08/24/how-to-use-a-fast-create/

You need to have two assignments in between where firstly you create a Lead type SObject Variable and assign the contract field to fields of this variable and in second assignment assign this Sobject variable to a SObject collection variable for Leads and Fast Create that one.

I have tested the below and it works correctly :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you create flow variables of primitively types - text, currency, percent, etc for the contract values you want to assign to the lead?

Then create a lead SObject, and assign its values from the individual primitive variables.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. Salesforce have provided a potential solution to my issue, but i'll give yours a shot if it doesn't work